# AngularJS: How to get elements off the scope in a link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that get's a JSON array from the controller off an attribute named stuff.  That part works fine.  What I'm trying to do now is make a link function that will use the length of that array and allow me to repeat both TR and TD elements to make a nicely formatted table.  I found a nice example of this on Stack but the issue I'm having is I am unable to get anything off my stuff attribute in the link function.  I just get undefined.

Controller:

```
function itemControl($http, $scope) {
  $http.get('doc/products.json').success(function (prodata) {
    $scope.data = prodata;
  });
}
```

Directive

```
app.directive("showcase", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: '<table>' + 
               '<colgroup span="2"></colgroup>' + 
                '<tr ng-repeat="items in stuff">' + 
                '<td>' + 
                 '<a  ng-href="{{items.SRC}}" Title="{{items.name}}" colorbox>' + 
                 '<img ng-src="{{items.SRC}}"></a>' + 
                '</td></tr></table>',
    scope: {
      stuff: "="
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      alert(scope.stuff);
    }

  };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="itemControl">
  <div showcase stuff="data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post a jsfiddle/plunkr, makes it easier for others to help. In the meantime, maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253471/isolate-scope-attributes-defined-with-are-undefined-disappear-in-directives-l

Comment: I will look at that.  I tried to build a fiddle of this but I get no results, I always struggle with angular inside fiddle I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because data is loaded from external JSON file so it is not available at time when "showcase" instance created. In order to catch this time you can use scope.$watch

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

Look this:

http://www.plnkr.co/edit/YdYVEWbmcUZZhUBs01pI